# Evaluate Integral (Romanian Olympiad)

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

$$ \int\cos x\cdot\cos^2(2x)\cdot\cos^3(3x)\cdot\cos^4(4x)\cdot\ldots\cdot\cos^{2002}(2002x)dx $$

Taken from the 2002 Romanian olympiad

Comment: well, if it is from Romanian olympiad then exist official solution?

Comment: @Li4ick I see you got an answer for your question called *Stereometry problem(difficult)* and you seem happy with it. Please consider accepting it.

Comment: Presumably you're integrating over one period, from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: @Li4ick Please provide bounds of integration or explicitly state that you seek to evaluate the indefinite integral.

Comment: A little bit of playing with the first few examples in Wolfram Alpha shows nothing resembling a reasonable pattern emerging: http://tinyurl.com/d8ql2nu

Answer (score 3):

*If* this is taken over $(0,2\pi)$ (or any multiple of this period):

By symmetry:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\prod_1^{n}\cos^k kx\,dx=2\int_0^{\pi}\prod_1^{n}\cos^k kx\,dx$$

Now let $x\to \dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$ and denote the integral like so:

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{ \frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)\,dx$$

Whenever $k$ is odd the transformation gives $\cos^k kx\to \pm\sin^k kx$ and $\cos^k kx\to \pm\cos^k kx$ otherwise. Hence $f$ is odd if there are an odd number of sines in the resulting product **i.e.** if there is an odd amount of odd numbers between $1$ and $n$.

Since there are exactly $1001$ odd $k$ such that $1\leq k\leq 2002$, the integrand is odd and therefore:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\prod_1^{2002}\cos^k kx\,dx=0$$

Comment: Can't add conditions at will...

Comment: @vonbrand It seems like this was the intended question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the integral is from $0$ to $2\pi$.  Then
$$
\cos \left(m(\frac{\pi}{2}-z)\right)=(-1)^m \cos \left( m(\frac{\pi}{2}+z)\right)
$$
so, if the integrand is $f(x)$,
$$
f(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=(-1)^N f(\frac{\pi}{2}+x),
$$
where 
$$
N=1^2+2^2+\cdots+2002^2=2676679005
$$
is odd, so
$$
f(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=- f(\frac{\pi}{2}+x).
$$
Then the portion of the integral from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ cancels out the portion from $0$ to $\pi/2$.  Also, the portion of the integral from $\pi$ to $3\pi/2$ equals $-\int_{-\pi/2}^0 f(x) \, dx$, which, since $f$ has period  $2\pi$, equals $-\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi} f(x) \, dx$.  Therefore the integral over $[0,2\pi]$ is $0$.

Comment: You don't really need to calculate $N$ to get that its odd